# Term for travel time per distance

Tags: kinematics, terminology, speed

Does the physics community have a term for the time per travel distance, $dt/dx$? I.e. the reciprocal of the speed. Runners call this their pace.

Comment: A related but not identical concept is perhaps [wavenumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber).

Answer (score 1):

No. Physicists don’t have a special term for $dt/dx$. They would just call it “inverse speed”. It doesn’t occur frequently enough to have its own name.